# Making RSS/ATOM feed in html/css/java/ruby

Tags: java, html, ruby, rss, atom-feed

I am trying to integrate an Atom or Rss feed with a ground-up site I am working on.  We are coding in html, css and java.

I have read other places that there are people trying to get certain aspects sorted out, or using plugins.  How would I go about integrating a feed into my site's homepage from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [deprecated their RSS feeds yesterday](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_90_day_deprecations).